# Why is it that pgp keyservers do not respond when I request keys?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I tried the Linux command line (bash 4.4.23 on Arch Linux kernel 4.18.16) with various key servers:

```
$ gpg -v --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys F434104235DA97EB
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
$ gpg -v --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F434104235DA97EB
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
$ gpg --debug-level 9 --keyserver  hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F434104235DA97EB
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- # Home: /home/user/.gnupg
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- # Config: /home/user/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK Dirmngr 2.2.11 at your service
gpg: DBG: connection to the dirmngr established
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> GETINFO version
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- D 2.2.11
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> KEYSERVER --clear hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> KS_GET -- 0xF434104235DA97EB
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- ERR 167772379 Server indicated a failure <Dirmngr>
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> BYE
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] stop
gpg: keydb: handles=0 locks=0 parse=0 get=0
gpg:        build=0 update=0 insert=0 delete=0
gpg:        reset=0 found=0 not=0 cache=0 not=0
gpg: kid_not_found_cache: count=0 peak=0 flushes=0
gpg: sig_cache: total=0 cached=0 good=0 bad=0
gpg: random usage: poolsize=600 mixed=0 polls=0/0 added=0/0
              outmix=0 getlvl1=0/0 getlvl2=0/0
gpg: rndjent stat: collector=0x0000000000000000 calls=0 bytes=0
gpg: secmem usage: 0/32768 bytes in 0 blocks
$
```

I tried the web interface of [https://pgp.surfnet.nl/](https://pgp.surfnet.nl/pks/lookup?search=F434104235DA97EB&fingerprint=on&op=index). It responds

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I tried the web interface of [https://pgp.mit.edu](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=F434104235DA97EB&op=index). It responds:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /pks/lookup.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

I tried the web interface at [https://pgp.key-server.io](https://pgp.key-server.io/pks/lookup?search=F434104235DA97EB&fingerprint=on&op=vindex) Reply is:

```
Hint! Double-check if the keyserver is up and running at the expected address:port (127.0.0.1:11369).
cURL error 52: Empty reply from server
#0 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::wrapException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException))
#1 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(132): GuzzleHttp\RequestFsm->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Transaction))
#2 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): GuzzleHttp\RequestFsm->GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Array)
#3 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/FutureResponse.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#5 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(134): GuzzleHttp\Message\FutureResponse::proxy(Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureArray), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(165): GuzzleHttp\RequestFsm->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Transaction))
#7 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/jenssegers/proxy/src/Adapter/Guzzle/GuzzleAdapter.php(54): GuzzleHttp\Client->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request))
#8 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/vendor/jenssegers/proxy/src/Proxy.php(80): Proxy\Adapter\Guzzle\GuzzleAdapter->send(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 'http://127.0.0....')
#9 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/src/ctubio/HKPProxy/Keyserver/Router.php(46): Proxy\Proxy->to('http://127.0.0....')
#10 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/src/ctubio/HKPProxy/Keyserver/Router.php(14): ctubio\HKPProxy\Keyserver\Router::getHKPResponse('/pks/lookup?sea...')
#11 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/src/ctubio/HKPProxy/Keyserver.php(19): ctubio\HKPProxy\Keyserver\Router::getResponse()
#12 /var/www/pgp.key-server.io/pub/php-proxy-keyserver.php(14): ctubio\HKPProxy\Keyserver::getResponse()
#13 {main}
```

Various other key servers say "No results found" to any key I request.

- What is going on? Is it a temporary problem? But why would all the key servers be offline at the same time?
- Does it have anything to do with access to every key server being blocked by my connection (Then why can I reach the web interfaces that will then fail?)?
- Is it that I am searching for invalid strings? I do not think so; I searched for a number of different ones, the one in the example here (F434104235DA97EB) should be the one that [signed this](https://github.com/apple/cups/releases/download/v2.2.8/cups-2.2.8-source.tar.gz.sig) package on github...
- Is it that I am not connecting to the correct key servers?

Comment: Tries: (1) Change the DNS server to google's `8.8.8.8` by adding to `/etc/resolv.conf`  the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google dns`. (2) Add `standard-resolver` to `/root/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` followed by `killall dirmngr` and `gpg --refresh-keys` and try again. (3) Add `0x` before the key so it becomes `0xF434104235DA97EB`. (4) Disable the firewall.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion. But please be patient. Not everyone is online every day and this question was asked almost a year ago. (1) DNS resolution is not the issue. DNS problems should result in different errors: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host` or `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name` or so. (2) Again about DNS resolution, which is not the problem. Also: Don't use root unless you really need to. (3) The `0x` is not necessary as explained in gpg's man page. (4) No. The problem also appears with permissive iptables rules and with iptables stopped in systemctl.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your command with `subkeys.pgp.net` and had the same problem. I searched a bit about that keyserver and I haven't found anything relevant, apart from people complaining about it failing. `keyserver.ubuntu.com` however works for me.

[Edit] Since `@blubberdiblub` noted, the `pool.sks-keyservers.net` keyserver is also gone. Try one of those instead:

- `hkps://keys.gnupg.net`
- `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com`
- `hkps://keys.openpgp.org`

---

**Old answer no longer valid but may be relevant for reference**

According to [this](http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Good_bye_subkeys_pgp_net__welcome_pool_sks_keyservers_net.html) there's a keyserver consisting of a pool of other keyservers more reliable. This one is: `pool.sks-keyservers.net`. There's more information on its [web page](https://sks-keyservers.net/).

I've tried usig `pool.sks-keyservers.net` as the keyserver and the command was able to import the key without problems.

So, to sum up and replying to your questions:

- Keyservers seem to not be reliable sometimes. Maybe those keyservers are old and unmaintained nowadays, they may be temporary offline or just dead. `pool.sks-keyservers.net` seems functional right now and reliable, but this may change over time.
- Web interface for those keyservers may render a page on your browser, but then key lookup may fail if the underlying keyserver where keys are stored is down, or they may not find the key if the server isn't synchronized with other keyservers.

Comment: I can confirm that the command works nicely with `pool.sks-keyservers.net`. So does that mean that the servers I tried back then are just constantly (then as now) overwhelmed?

Comment: On a different note: I'll wait until the end of the bounty by @AaronZolotor before accepting an answer.

Comment: I don't think `pool.sks-keyservers.net` works anymore. Going forward, use `keys.gnupg.net` instead.